# Populating data in dropdown from rest api calls using angular js and ngrepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to get select-box to start off with a pre-filled option using ng-repeat with AngularJS

I have read a lot of articles using ng-options instead of ng-repeat, but I want to use ng-repeat for this case. Since the same HTML code is working for other pages I would like to keep it that way.

Since I am new to angular I am not quite sure why it's working in some pages and not on others

Here's the HTML:

```
<select id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control required" ng-model="ToDoProp.BMW">
    <option value="">Choose One:</option>
    <option value="{{item.Title}}" ng-repeat="item in bmwProp | orderBy:'Title' track by $index"> {{item.Title}}</option>
</select>
```

How ever this code is injecting

```
<select id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control required ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty" ng-model="ToDoProp.BMW"><option value="? string:value ?" selected="selected"></option>
```

after investing so much time in reading articles I am still not able to figure out the problem. Please help..!!

Comment: how do you pre-select the option? is there any js code to show?

Comment: You'll need to show your JS - what is bmwProp? Have you checked to make sure that array (or object) is available to that template code?